# How to Pass parameter in ADO.NET Source SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Hello I need some help This will be my first SSIS package and I am learning as I go. So far this is what I have.

I created a Control Flow. Then I created three ADO.Net connections, twofor source and one for destination. Then I created data flow tasks it copies data from a table in one database into a corresponding table in another database on the same server.  data flow task has an 2 ADO NET Source and ADO NET Destination. The destination simply maps the fields together.

Okay, so far so good. This is my problem. Some of the source queries have date criteria. An example would be:

```
SELECT --Code Here 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, call_date, 112) BETWEEN '6/1/2013' AND  '7/1/2013'
```

I want to replace these hard-coded dates with variables. Something like:

```
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, call_date, 112) BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDATE
```

I've read several posts and tried to do what is being described, but it's not sinking in. So please use my example to tell me how to do this. It would be nice if I could have the package prompt me for the Date when I run it, but I'd be very happy just to learn how to pass a variable into the query.

This is the only solution I know because I just a beginner here in SSIS package I hope someone can help me

Comment: hi have you given a look to this example? is really simple an shows what your're looking for http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.ch/2008/10/prompting-for-parameter-in-ssis.html

Comment: Any particular reason you're using the *ADO.NET* components? If you don't mind terribly, you can switch to an *OLE DB Source* component which allows a query from a variable. You can then create an expression for that variable for the functionality you want.

Comment: @TsSkTo It's Just I know how to do my project in ado.net maybe you can tell me on how to this in OLEDB?

Comment: @Raphael It helps me a bit but it is not what I needed in my Package

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582211/ssis-passing-parameters-to-an-ado-net-source-query?rq=1 if it doesn't work I'll put an answer down with the OLEDB semantics

Comment: There's more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297301/how-to-pass-parameters-to-an-ado-net-source-in-ssis?rq=1

Comment: @TsSkTo the first one that you give me is not what I need and the second one does not seem answer the question

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 Availability Groups, you can't use OLE DB in situations where you need multi-subnet failover support. While official Microsoft guidance is to use ODBC, ADO.Net performance is much better. I found the answer by OzrenTkalcecKrznaric to be the cleanest technique. Since we had OLE DB sources with Data Access mode "SQL Command from Variable", I just copied the existing variable expressions into the DFT property expression for the replacement ADO.Net data source.

Answer (score 65):

Since none of the answers here actually answer the question (pay attention to the **ADO.NET source**, not OLE DB!), here's the real answer.

In SSIS you can't parametrize ADO.NET source. You have to use a workaround.

Luckily, there are few workarounds. One would be creating Script Component that acts like source and code it. However, one can't always easily convert the existing resource into script, especially when he lacks ADO.NET programming knowledge.

There is another workaround, and that would be creating the SQL Query **before** the ADO.NET Source takes action. However, when you open ADO.NET source, you will notice that Data access mode doesn't allow variable input. So, how do you proceed?

You want to dynamically set the SQL expression of the ADO.NET source, so you have to tell your **data flow task** to configure the SSIS ADO.NET source component by using Expression.

To make the long story short (or not-quite-so-short :), do this:

- in your package, enter your data flow task with source/destination components
- click anywhere on the background, to have Task properties shown in Property panel
- in Property panel find Expressions property, that can configure various data source/destination properties, and open it using ellipsis button (...)
- under Property, select SQL Command property of your source (e.g. [ADO.NET source].[SqlCommand]) to add one row
- click ellipsis button for the row to open Expression Builder
- build your dynamic query in the Expression Builder

The last step could be somewhat cumbersome for date/datetime parameter. However, here's the example, for your convenience:

```
"SELECT * FROM YOUR_SOURCE_TABLE WHERE your_date_column = '" + 
  (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(@[User::VAR_CONTAINING_DATE]) + "-" +
  (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[User::VAR_CONTAINING_DATE]) + "-" +
  (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(@[User::VAR_CONTAINING_DATE]) + "'"
```

HTH

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks for the help

Comment: Smells like `SQL INJECTION` :/

Comment: I sure would like to see this expression to be exploited for sql injection attack.

Comment: Note that after setting the expression **ADO.NET source** might show an error as source will not have SQL in it, but after running **SSIS** SQL will be automatically updated and errors will be resolved.

Comment: It hard to read, but it it is true, you can apply expression and assign ADONET.Source.SQLCommand Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 4):

**[ ADO.NET AS A SOURCE TYPE SOLUTION ]**

**Step 1**
Create variables for each parameter you would like to use.

[image]

**Step 2**
Select the task on the Control Flow tab which executes the query

**Step 3** Go to the properties of this task to select the Expressions by clicking on the "..." button

[image]

**Step 4** Select the command property and click on the "..." button
[image]

**Step 5** Now you can construct your query here including the variables you defined in Step 1. Save when done. Enjoy!

Comment: This is the correct approach for the given question. It is not detail information. Use this reference for complete details. Basically, the ado source exposes the sql command property. This can be replaced as an expression from the control flow view. 
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/04/10/forum-faq-how-do-i-use-parameters-in-an-ssis-ado-net-source/

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how i do it.

On your control flow create an Execute SQL task.  Set up the DB connection.  In the SQLStatment do something like.

```
select getdate() -1 startDate , getdate() endDate
```

Set ResultSet on the genral tab to Single Row.   Go to the Result Set tab click add Give a Result name something like StartDate then add a new Variable.

```
Name: startDate  (must be the same name as the alius in the select)
Namespace: user 
type:  DateTime
Value:  02-09-2013
```

Now when that runs it should fill in a user variable with the current date and yesterdays date.   Do the same thing form EndDate

Create your second  Execute SQL task Link it to the first.  Add this SQL statment.  ? will be your variables

```
select stuff
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, call_date, 112) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Go to Paramater mapping.
Add one

```
Variable Name should be something like User::StartDate 
Direction Input
Datetype: Nvarchar
Parameter name: 0 
Parameter size: 0
```

add the second one

```
Variable Name should be something like User::EndDate 
Direction Input
Datetype: Nvarchar
Parameter name: 1
Parameter size: 0
```

When you add a third one just add Parameter name 2...

Run it.

Comment: I added a blog post for you.  The pictures might make it easer to understand.  Enjoy SSIS welcome to the fun.  http://daimto.com/ssis-package-variables/

Answer (score -2):

Here's the OLE DB Apporach:

Create some parameters for your package. If you make them Required then they are, well, required and your package won't run without some values. The field in the Value column will be the default and used for debugging.

[image]

Then create a variable and add an expression:

[image]

[image]

The Expressions editor uses a washed out version of C#(if you were curious)

Also *Make sure to add spaces in your string in between variables* Its hard to see but AND has a space on either side like so:

" AND "

I almost forgot. The values for yor parameters have to be in 'singleQuotes'. This can be done in one of two ways: You can either include the quotes when you give a value to the string or you can add some quotes in the expression(what I usually do).

Adding them in the expression would look something like this:

`"some stuff " + "'" + @[variable] + "'"`

Click evaluate expression to see if your variable is holding the correct string.

The last step is to add an OLE DB Source, set up the connection(if you don't have one yet) and add the query from variable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving me something new to play with.   Created an expression with (DT_WSTR, 30)(DT_DBDATE) DATEADD("Day",7, GETUTCDATE() ) worked like a charm to.    I wasnt aware of the SQL command from Variable feature. I need to try that.

Comment: This is good information but seems distracting as the question specifies ADO.NET. I'm thinking there is a reason Microsoft didn't bring this technique forward from OLE DB?

Comment: @ffejrekaburb note the comments on the original question. The I suggested the OP switch to OLE DB and they specifically asked for the solution.