# SQL Command text with parameter OLEDB Source

Tags: sql, ssis, prepared-statement, oledb

I am working with SQL Server Integration Services 2008. In my Data Flow task I got a OLEDB source. I choose SQL command as the Data Access mode and following is my sql text

```
Select * from table1 where ID=?
```

And from parameters tab my Parameter Name is zero "0" and value is coming from a package level variable.

I tried to replace the parameter name with "Parameter0" but I always get the same error that

```
Error: "No Value given for one or more required parameters"
```

But there is a value for my variable

Comment: You changed the parameter name to 0 and then "I tried to replace the parameter name with "Parameter0"" why would you change it back? Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? When you run the package, the dataflow component, or just punching the _Preview_ button?

Comment: When I push the preview button.

Comment: @billinkc because by default the parameter name is Parameter0 but MSDN says for OLDDB connections it should be "0".

Comment: I get the same error while just trying the preview. Have you tried running it? Heres a work around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093362/how-to-pass-parameter-in-ado-net-source-ssis/20102133#20102133

Comment: @TsSKTo I am doing the same now.Just wanted to avoid more variables to write commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing the right thing, but it is the "Preview" that is not working for parameterized source tasks. Try executing the package and you should be ok.