# How to pass a variable to an SSIS package to be used in query

Tags: variables, parameters, ssis, parameter-passing

I'm currently having an issue when trying to import data using SSIS.
I have an SSIS package that moves data from one server / database to another server / database.
At the moment the query will take all rows in the source DB and move it to the destination.
I need to change this so that only a select few rows are moved using the ID as the filter.
I need to pass an ID in as a parameter which is to be used to filter the dataset to only return the select few rows. How does one do this?
I currently have a simple SSIS package with 2 dataflow objects (source & destination) but from what I've been looking at I may need to change this somewhat.

```
SELECT 
ID, 
[Product Type], 
[Product Title]
FROM [View]
where ID = <This should be provided from outside the package>
```

The package will eventually be triggered by TSQL / Stored Procedure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parameters. In SSIS a question mark `?` is being used as a parameter and its order determines the parameter name. Just use this SQL (inside `Source` task):

```
SELECT 
ID, 
[Product Type], 
[Product Title]
FROM [View]
where ID = ?
```

..then click the `Parameters` button:

[image]
*Please note that `Preview` button (if you will try it) won't work (it will throw an error) but you can ignore that and simply try run your package as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395364/sql-command-text-with-parameter-oledb-source).*

..and then change the parameter name to simply `0` (zero) and set it to your variable:

[image]

Should work well.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks for your prompt reply :)