# SQL SSIS Get All New Rows

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package which copies data from one DB to another.

Looking to find out how I can make the SSIS package only copy the new rows from the source DB to the destination DB. My idea was to use something like `WHERE CreatedDate >= LAST_SSIS_RUN_DATE` but not sure what the syntax for the last run date of the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put an `InsertedDate` column in your destination table, and use the latest value from that column as your LastRun date, or
2. As the last step of your package, populate a table with meta data about your package, like when it finished, how many rows, success/failure, and anything else you might like to store.   Use the last row of the table to know when the package last ran.

Comment: Thanks, I have created an Execute SQL Task which gets one value, the last inserted date from my destination table. I am stuck at the next part, passing this value to the Data Flow Task which is doing the copying between the two tables. Using the ADO.net connector. I am not sure what the syntax is in the SQL query for the Data Flow Task to call on the result of the Execute SQL Task.

Comment: I am not able to use the OLD DB connection only ADO.net and that does not have any Parameters button like the link you have mentioned above.

Comment: In that case:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093362/how-to-pass-parameter-in-ado-net-source-ssis