# SSIS Use Derived Column to Dynamically Add Column(s) that do not Exists in Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to pull tables over from two source systems into a consolidated destination server. We have multiple business units that reside on separate source systems and for the most part have the same table structures, however one of the source systems was upgraded to a newer version and has some columns that the other sources do not have.

I have the data flow tasks right now setup to run inside a for each loop which finds and loops through each of my sources. I need the query to change based on the source system to include the missing columns. I'm hoping I might be able to do this dynamically by using derived column to add the columns if the column(s) in question doesn't exist and if it does exist, I want the package to ignore the derived column and move on.

I've tried also writing out my queries to variables but I can't quite figure out how to have the DFT choose a specific query variable based on the source connection.

**EDIT: Table comparison example below**:

```
--Updated Source
SELECT [ProductID]
  ,[ProductNumber]
  ,[ReorderPoint]
  ,[ListPrice]
  ,[SizeUnitMeasureCode]
  ,[WeightUnitMeasureCode]
  ,[Class]
  ,[Style]  
  ,[ProductSubcategoryID]
  ,[ProductModelID]
  ,[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Sales].[Product];

--Outdated Source
SELECT [ProductID]
  ,[ProductNumber]
  ,[ReorderPoint]
  ,[ListPrice]
  ,[SizeUnitMeasureCode]
  ,[WeightUnitMeasureCode]
  ,[Class]
  ,[Style]  
  ,NULL AS [ProductSubcategoryID]
  ,NULL AS [ProductModelID]
  ,[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Sales].[Product];
```

I want to be able to pull all columns including those that are missing from the outdated source. The columns noted with NULL AS are the missing columns in question.

Comment: A source, in SSIS, has to be well defined. It sounds like the tables aren't consistent, so don't have the same number of columns. As such you'll need to use different data flows depending on the definition of the table. You can't have a source that *might* have the column, but *might* not. Alternatively, you could just get your clients to update their software, as it seems they should have.

Comment: In a perfect world, yes, I would love for the sources to all be on the same version, but unfortunately that's not my case. What I want to do is to pull the columns that are missing as NULL AS [MissingColumnName] from the outdated source systems. Would it not be possible to do this in a semi-dynamic fashion and pass in a pre-defined query based on the source connection?

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to use a dynamic query to define a statement that returns a dataset that has the same definition, regardless of the instance it is used in; that won;t be particularly pretty.

Comment: Do you have examples of this being done by chance? I have a vague idea of what that needs to look like, but I'm struggling to piece it all together.

Comment: Not really, when we don't have any details of the columns that are (or aren't) in your table.

Comment: I updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like this solution, but it *might* work. As I mentioned, you might be able to construct a dynamic statement and then build the query from that. This is ugly but, like I said, SSIS expect consistent definitions so if youcan't give it that, there are hoops you must jump through.

This is untested as well, but hopefully will give you the idea.

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnList table (OrdinalPosition int IDENTITY(1,1),
                           ColumnName sysname,
                           ColumnDatatype sysname);


--The following datatypes are completely guessed
INSERT INTO @ColumnList
VALUES(N'ProductID',N'int'),
      (N'ProductNumber',N'int'),
      (N'ReorderPoint',N'int'),
      (N'ListPrice',N'decimal'),
      (N'SizeUnitMeasureCode',N'decimal'); --You get the idea

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(20) = N',' + @CRLF + N'       ';

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + 
              STRING_AGG(ISNULL(QUOTENAME(c.[name]),N'CONVERT(' + QUOTENAME(CL.ColumnDatatype) + N',NULL') + N') AS ' + QUOTENAME(CL.ColumnName),@Delimiter) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CL.OrdinalPosition) + @CRLF +
              N'FROM Sales.Product;'
FROM @ColumnList CL
     LEFT JOIN sys.columns c
          JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                           AND t.[name] = N'Product'
          JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                            AND s.[name] = N'dbo'
                             ON CL.ColumnName = c.[name];

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

You *should* be able to use this as the definition for SSIS's source and it *should* create a dataset with all the columns you want, even if the table doesn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this semi-dynamically in SSIS is to use an Expression in the data flow source queries that replaces the column name with a literal null when connecting to systems that lack some of the columns.  Or to you a Script Source in your data flow and replace the missing columns in code.

Comment: How would I go about using an expression in the source query? Since my data flow tasks are contained in a for each loop, it's going to hit both the updated and outdated source systems. I obviously want all columns that are potentially available, but if I'm missing the column [item_code] from the outdated source, I want to still pull that column but as a NULL. I don't know how to go about doing that without also pulling it as a NULL from the updated source as well.

Comment: Both approaches are covered in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093362/how-to-pass-parameter-in-ado-net-source-ssis